# Making multiple same http request in optimized way

Tags: java, java-websocket

my code is looks like

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    getResponse();
}
```

I am making the request in for loop. Don't want to open the request every time and want to optimize this better way. How wan we do it in a better way?

```
public static void getReponse() {
    try {
        // Construct data
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

        // Send data
        URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80/cgi");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            // Process line...
        }
        wr.close();
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: Remove the for loop, and thus send the request only once?

Comment: Use this link https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management

Comment: @SuseendranP Your link is irrelevant. The op isn't using that library.